# using compass mixins in scss files compiled by gulp in Laravel Elixir

Tags: laravel, sass, gulp, compass-sass, compass

I want to use Compass mixins and Capabilities in scss files that should compiled with **Gulp** tasks in **laravel Elixir**.

For example , I have two scss files named `my-styles.css` and `app.scss` in `resource/assets/sass` directory :

This is `my-styles.scss` file :

```
@import "compass/css3";
body{
      opacity: 1.0;
      animation: test;
      color: red;
      text-align: center;
      a:link{
        background-color: red;
        text-decoration: none ;
        &.span{
          color: red;
          @include border-radius(5px);
        }
      }

}
```

And this is `app.scss` file Content :

```
a{
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: rotate(30deg) scale(10);
}
```

And to compile this scss files and combine them to a file name `all.css` in `public/css` directory , I write this :

```
var elixir  = require('laravel-elixir');
var gulp    = require('gulp');
var compass = require('gulp-compass');
var sass    = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('compile', function () {
    return gulp
        .src(['my-styles.scss', 'app.scss'])
        .pipe(sass({compass: true, sourcemap: true, style: 'compressed'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/all.css'));
});

elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;
elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.task('compile');
});
```

after running `gulp` command in console this messages are shown:

```
D:\wamp\www\newProject>gulp
[12:36:48] Using gulpfile D:\wamp\www\newProject\gulpfile.js
[12:36:48] Starting 'default'...
[12:36:48] Starting 'task'...
[12:36:48] Starting 'compile'...
[12:36:48] Finished 'task' after 17 ms
[12:36:48] Finished 'default' after 21 ms
[12:36:48] Finished 'compile' after 26 ms
```

But No file is created in `public` directory.

what is Problem ?

Comment: What does this have to do with Compass?  Did you verify that this even worked before importing Compass and trying to use its mixins?

Comment: Compass blows...  consider yourself lucky this isn't working, and move on.  If you need a mixin library, use Bourbon instead.